# Run cmd script without writing it to disk as a batch file from within Delphi 2010 application

Tags: delphi, batch-file, delphi-2010

Is there a way to run a complex command script (batch file) without writing it to disk?

I would like to type my script inside a memo and then `ShellExecute` it on button press without writing it to disk first.

Comment: No, there is not. CMD.EXE expects to parse a text file to obtain the commands, or receive them from the command line. If you're doing something that needs a script, it will have to be in a file.

Comment: It depends on what the script actually does. Like you said, commands could be passed to CMD.EXE as command-line parameters, so you could shell out CMD.EXE with the `/C` parameter followed by a command. That would mean starting a new CMD.EXE process for each command. You could chain multiple commands together in a single shell-out using the '&&' operator. But then you are getting into analyzing the script to know what is safe, what is chainable, etc. Probably best to switch to `IActiveScript` instead so you can run VBScript/JavaScript code in memory instead of running CMD.EXE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I tested and it works.
Thanks for the answers!

```
var: script_lines:string;

script_lines:='hostname & getmac & ipconfig /all & tasklist';

ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('cmd.exe'), PChar('/k '+script_lines), nil, SW_SHOW);
```